# JPA CriteriaQuery compare String date(112019) To date

Tags: postgresql, hibernate-criteria

I am using postgres sql database.
Let say I have a column in postressql DB like this:

```
date (Column name), Varchar(Data type), 112019 (Value)

Query - select c.* from SOMETHING c where TO_DATE(c.date, 'MMYY') = '2019-11-01';

I am trying to convert above query into JPA CriteriaQuery as following but getting exception. please help to convert above sql query into criteria builder

    CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<SOMETHING> cq = cb.createQuery(SOMETHING.class);
    Root<SOMETHING> cafRoot = cq.from(SOMETHING.class);
    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>(); 
    predicates.add(cb.equal(cb.function("TO_DATE", Date.class, cafRoot.get("date"), cb.literal("MMYYYY")), date));
    cq.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
    final TypedQuery<SOMETHING> query = entityManager.createQuery(cq);
    query.getResultList();


    INFO  2019-12-10 08:54:13,360 XNIO-1 task-1    Input field for search records: 
    INFO  2019-12-10 08:54:13,423 XNIO-1 task-1   o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator  HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
    WARN  2019-12-10 08:54:13,652 XNIO-1 task-1   o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 22007
    ERROR 2019-12-10 08:54:13,652 XNIO-1 task-1   o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   ERROR: invalid value "AB" for "MM"
    Detail: Value must be an integer.
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! So, what exactly is your question?

Comment: please show the SQL statement that Hibernate generates

Comment: select generatedAlias0 from SOMETHING as generatedAlias0 where function('TO_DATE', generatedAlias0.date, :param0)=:param1